# how to add an origin in Cors while Application is contantly running (Asp.Net mvc core)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I am creating a web app on asp.net core. scenario is such that, a user will register his website (https://www.example.com) on my application and my application will provide some services to his website (https://www.example.com). What I want is To add his website to Origins list in CORS while my application is constantly running.

```
services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("myPolicy", builder =>
{            
    builder.WithOrigins("http://www.example1.com","https://www.example2.com")
                       .AllowAnyMethod()
                       .AllowAnyHeader()
                       .AllowCredentials();
}
```

Now my application is running, and a User#3 gets his website(www.example3.com) registered on my applications. Now I have to add his website(www.example3.com) in Origins. and I don't want my application to get restart. I'am stuck. How can I do that ??

Comment: I found [this](https://www.tpeczek.com/2017/04/reconfiguring-cors-policy-in-aspnet.html), hope it helps

Comment: @B.Lec  Here he used "ICorsPolicyAccessor". I'm unable to understand where did he get this interface from..

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51901889/net-core-dynamic-cors-with-branched-pipeline ?

Comment: @Muhammad Naveed it must be a custom interface